# OpenAI gym breakout-ram-v4 unable to learn

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

I am using Q learning and the program should be able to play the game after some tries but it is not learning even when the epsilon value if 0.1.

I have tried changing the batch size the memory size. I have changed the code to give -1 reward if the player dies.

```python
import gym 
import numpy as np  
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from time import time
import keyboard
import sys
import time


env = gym.make("Breakout-ram-v4")
observationSpace = env.observation_space
actionSpace=  env.action_space
episode = 500

class Model_QNN :
    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = []
        self.MAX_MEMORY_TO_USE = 60_000
        self.gamma = 0.9
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(128,1)),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation="relu"),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(actionSpace.n , activation=  "softmax")
            ])
        self.model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse",metrics=["accuracy"])

    def remember(self, steps , done):
        self.memory.append([steps,done])
        if(len(self.memory) >= self.MAX_MEMORY_TO_USE):
            del self.memory[0]
    def replay(self,batch_size= 32):
        states, targets_f = [], []
        if(len(self.memory)< batch_size) :
            return 
        else: 
            mini = random.sample(self.memory,batch_size)
            states ,targets  = [],  [] 
            for steps , done  in mini :
                target= steps[2] ;
                if not done :
                    target = steps[2]  + (self.gamma* np.amax(self.model.predict(steps[3].reshape(1,128,1))[0]))
                target_f = self.model.predict(steps[0].reshape(1,128,1))
                target_f[0][steps[1]] = target
                states.append(steps[0])
                targets.append(target_f[0])
            self.model.fit(np.array(states).reshape(len(states),128,1), np.array(targets),verbose=0,epochs=10)
    def act(self,state,ep):
        if(random.random()< ep):
            action = actionSpace.sample()
        else :
            np.array([state]).shape
            action= self.model.predict(state.reshape(1,128,1))
            action = np.argmax(action)
        return  action;
    def saveModel (self):
        print("Saving")
        self.model.save("NEWNAMEDONE")
    def saveBackup(self,num):
        self.model.save("NEWNAME"+str(int(num)))
def main():
    agent= Model_QNN();
    epsilon=0.9
    t_end = time.time()
    score=  0
    for e in range(2000):
        print("Working on episode : "+str(e)+" eps "+str(epsilon)+" Score  " + str(score))
        preState = env.reset()
        preState,reward,done,_ = env.step(1)
        mainLife=5
        done = False
        score=  0
        icount = 0
        render=False
        if e % 400 ==0 and not e==0:
            render =True
        while not done:
            icount+=1
            if render:
                env.render()
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                agent.saveBackup(100)
                agent.saveModel()
                quit()
            rewrd=0
            if ( _["ale.lives"] < mainLife ):
                mainLife-=1
                rewrd=-1
                action=1
            else: 
                action = agent.act(preState,epsilon)
            newState,reward,done,_ = env.step(action)
            if rewrd ==-1 :
                reward =-1
            agent.remember([preState/255,action,reward,newState/255],done);
            preState= newState;
            score+=reward 
            if done :
                break
        agent.replay(1024)
        if epsilon >= 0.18 :
           epsilon = epsilon * 0.995;
        if ((e+1)%500==0):
            agent.saveBackup((e+1)/20)
    agent.saveModel()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

There is no error message the program should learn and it is not

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Softmax on your output layer?
If you want to use Softmax use Cross-Entropy as your loss. However, it looks like you're trying to implement a value based learning system. The activation function on your output layer should be linear.

I suggest you try your implementation on Cartpole-v0 then LunarLanding-v2 first.
Those are solved environments and a great place to sanity check your code.

"There is no error message the program should learn and it is not."
Welcome to ML where things fail silently.